# Gitlab push origin master

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gitlab

I have a new version of gitlab installed with nginx. I can access the front end no problem, I can create users/add keys, and create projects. After creating my first project I attempted to follow the directions on the project page, but I keep getting this error. I have checked all the logs and can't find anything relevant:

```
git push -u origin master
```

returns

```
/home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:71:in `get': undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x00000001ca76b8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:31:in `allowed?'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:59:in `validate_access'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:23:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

As per the other help I found online I then tried:

```
ssh git@myhost
```

and get:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
/home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:71:in `get': undefined method `request_uri' for #    <URI::Generic:0x00000002a60d40> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:38:in `discover'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:77:in `user'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:82:in `username'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:36:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
Connection to [ip_addr] closed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after days of googling I finally tried two things and the problem is resolved:

- Updated my EC2 instance from a t1.micro to a m1.small, gitlab
  apparently requires closer to a gig of memory.
- During my configuration I set the url in the config files to the ip
  of the server, I changed those references to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try a git verion that is <= Git-1.8.4 ,
because it seems new version might has problem in push while use https.

Comment: ok, on linux I don't have problem, I am using 1.8.4, but on windows I have similar problem like yours, so I change version to 1.8.2, then it's fixed.